# Two picker views in the same UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

I have a `UIViewController` that contains two picker views. For some reason when I run the project one picker view is overshadowing the other. How can I set the positions, height and other parameters in code?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using two picker view ? You can change the content of the pickerview when needed.
Even if u want to use two of them, the picker would be at the bottom anyways. Use show and hide property of the pickerview to handle your required task

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `-initWithFrame:` method (assuming that you're instantiating the view in code). Here's an example showing to picker views -

```
UIPickerView *myPickerView1 = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
[self.view addSubview:myPickerView1];

UIPickerView *myPickerView2 = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 320)];
[self.view addSubview:myPickerView2];
```

If you see this image below, they are not overshadowing one another. I hope this easy explanation helps. Welcome to iOS Development!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way

```
 //first picker
   optionPicker1 = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 200)];
  [self.view addSubview:optionPicker1];



  //second picker
   optionPicker2 = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 200)];
  [self.view addSubview:optionPicker2];
```